# Files are not in project navigator eventhough project compiles and can search for them

Tags: ios, xcode9

The problem started when I got into the project and saw I have no scheme. Couldn't create new scheme except for the cocoa-pods target. Then I went into my project via finder, and noticed that the project was backedup into the iCloud, and when downloaded it it appeared in the schemes and ran fine.

So I am with this project for a while now, started it in xcode 9 and already released a few versions to the store. Today I open the project for more developing, and I notice that I cannot see the files in the navigator. If I search for them I can go into them and edit. If I am running it, it builds and runs perfectly. Only problem is that I cannot navigate between files, and cannot find the storyboard in the search, so cannot open it at all.
I tried -

- Hard clean
- Delete derived data
- reset computer and xcode.

But still cannot see the files in navigator.
Screen shot of navigator added:

[image]

Comment: Go to your project root folder and run `pod install` again and click on the xcframework to open the project. Seems like in one of your previous commits to repo you removed the reference to file added to project or somehow screwed up the project schema. Regenerating it should solve your problem

Comment: Hey friend, thanks for the comment. It did not help as I’ve already tried.. but I dragged the files into the project and can now navigate between the files, but still see the proj like jn screen shot (with extra folders)

Comment: Sorry but I din get  "proj like jn screen shot" can you please elaborate ?

Comment: The screen shot added shows the project as not clickable, its still like that

Comment: hmmm interesting, lemme check if I could anyway reproduce that and will get back to you :) Seems interesting problem to me hence +1

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciated

Comment: One last thing if you could try (its safe I tested it on my project so dont worry ) Go to your project .xcodeproj right click and select show package contents delete the xcuserdata folder and now go back to terminal and run `pod install` and now open workspace and lemme know if it helps :) its important for you to fix it before u make commit to your repo else your repo will also get corrupted

Comment: Dude you rock! it worked.. please post as answer

Comment: am glad it helped :)

Comment: Added the comment as answer below :) Feel free to accept if you think that will help somebody else as well in future :) happy coding :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in comments above I am adding the comment as answer, you can try deleting the xcuserdata folder inside .xcodeproj and re-run the `pod install` to solve the problem.

In order to do that, go to your `.xcodeproj` right click and select **show package contents**

[image]

Once it opens the finder window with contents inside it, simply delete the **xcuserdata** folder

[image]

Now get back to your project root folder in terminal and run `pod install` once done open the project using `workspace`.

That should solve your problem :)

Happy coding:)

Comment: @eyzuky : Thanks mate :)